# Button not appearing and hover not working either

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hover

My button and hover were working before I started on the Javascript so im a bit confused as to why its not working or showing up now,
This is my first javascript project so would love some help explaining my error and how I can fix it.
Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/AoifeLarkin/odqhxtmj/#&togetherjs=2GOviaBkd1

Link to JSFiddle of Code

```
<html>
   

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Animal Quiz</title>
<link href="Styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

 <body>
   
   <div id="wrapper">
     <h1>Animal Quiz</h1>

     <!--Start Button for Quiz to Begin-->
     <div class="start_button"><button>Start Quiz</button></div>

     <!--Box for Quiz-->
     <div class="box">
       <header>
         <h2>Question 1</h2>
       </header>
       <main>
         <div class="q">
           <!--Block Element-->
           <!--<span>The biggest predator in the animal kingdom?</span>-->
           <!--Inline Element-->
         </div>
         <div class="option_list">
           <!--<div class="option">
             <span>Whale</span>
           </div>
           <div class="option">
             <span>Lion</span>
           </div>
           <div class="option">
             <span>Crocodile</span>
           </div>-->
         </div>

       </main>



       <!--Footer for the quiz box-->

       <footer>
         <div class="total_q">
           <span> 1 of 15 Questions</span>
         </div>
         <button class="next_button">Next Question</button>


       </footer>


     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shuld use debugger (or console). You have not definied the array `questions`.From this point on, the execution of the entire code will stop (so nothing will be working).

Comment: so my first question is appearing but then the button for next question disappears so i can't click to go to the next question.

Comment: Please, send the link of the new code, or fresh at the link (I only found the old code at the link).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/AoifeLarkin/dmbt67kx/2/#&togetherjs=3LvhiSE0S7                                              new link didnt change much

Comment: nothing seems to come up when I use the debugger

Comment: Check the css again... Perhaps a style setting for the new elements... Javascript and html do not cause errors.

Comment: i just changed opacity to  be 1 and now it has appeared but still doesn't do anything.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/AoifeLarkin/29pyb0zx/1/#&togetherjs=9zl8IDvv3p here is a new link to the fix

Comment: At the `next_button.onclick` and at the `qCounter ` function you use `question.length`, but you should use `questions.length`, and at `qCounter` you call `document.querySelector('total_q')` instead `.total_q` (you have again forgot check the debugger).

Comment: The `z-index` property of the new box is 5, but at the `next_button` only 1, so if you click on the button, you don't click this, only the `.activeBox` "above" the button! You should set upper the `z-index` of the `next_button`

Comment: I’ll have a look again, thank you so much for you’re help hopefully this will sort it, you’re amazing

Comment: So what you’re saying is to add z-index:5  to next_button.

Comment: I have tried it since and it did not completely solve the problem. I added `document.addEventListener ('click', function (e) {console.log (e.target)})` when I click on the button, it adds the html element (I think it's somehow related to the `footer` protrudes from the `body`).

Comment: okay ill have a look at that now thank you